# Evaluate symbolic expression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate a function which is an infinite cosine series at some input values.

**EDIT**: Posting an image to describe what the infinite series looks like
[image]

I wrote the following code to describe it in MATLAB.

```
function func = cosfun_hat(a,i)
    syms m x;

    assume(m,'integer');
    assumeAlso(m > 0);

    sum(x) = sqrt(1-a^2)*symsum(sqrt(2)*a^m*cos(i*sym(pi)*x*2^m+1),m,0,Inf);
    func(x) = sum(x);
end
```

I want to evaluate the returned 'function' `func` to get numerical values for some input range say `x_in = 0:0.001:1`.

```
%Trying to evaluate func at x = 2
%In the command window I write
func = cosfun_hat(0.5,2);
func(2)
```

which returns the symbolic expression:

```
(2^(1/2)*3^(1/2)*sum((1/2)^m*(exp(- pi*exp(m*log(2))*4*i - i)/2 + exp(pi*exp(m*log(2))*4*i + i)/2), m == 0..Inf))/2
```

I tried using `subs` to evaluate the expression:

```
%In the command window
syms y;
w(y) = func(y);
y = 2;
subs(w);
```

But that returns the same symbolic expression. I am quite new to symbolic MATLAB.

Thanks!

**EDIT** Based on the comment by @NickyMattsson I tried

```
vpa(func(2))
```

which returns the numerical value of the expression. 
However,
`vpa(func(0.1))` returns a symbolic expression:

```
ans =

1.2247448713915890490986420373529*numeric::sum((1/2)^m*(exp(- (pi*exp(m*log(2))*i)/5 - i)/2 + exp((pi*exp(m*log(2))*i)/5 + i)/2), m == 0..Inf)
```

The same problem with using `double(func(0.1))`, `double` doesn't return anything and is stuck.

Comment: Does `vpa(func(2))` solve your problem?

Comment: @NickyMattsson Thanks for your comment. `vpa(func(2))` returns numerical value.However if I use `vpa(func(0.1))`, MATLAB returns `1.2247448713915890490986420373529*numeric::sum((1/2)^m*(exp(- (pi*exp(m*log(2))*i)/5 - i)/2 + exp((pi*exp(m*log(2))*i)/5 + i)/2), m == 0..Inf)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it without using symbolic MATLAB.

```
function func = cosfun_hat(a,i,x)
    m = 0;
    sum = zeros(1,length(x));
    sum2 = Inf(1,length(x));
    while max(sum2-sum) > 1e-16
        disp(m);
        sum2 = sum;
        sum = sum + sqrt(1-a^2)*sqrt(2)*a^m*cos(i*pi*x*2^(m+1));
        m = m+1;

    end
    func = sum;
end
```

The sum converges inside 100 iterations.

Now if I do,

```
%In command window
x_in = -2:0.001:2;
f = cosfun_hat(0.6,2,x_in);
plot(x_in,f);
```

I get the plot:

[image]

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Use this command

```
double(func(2))
```

Comment: `double(func(2))` returns a numerical value.`double(func(0.1))` doesn't return anything. As I have said in my question, I need to evaluate on a range of values `x_in = 0:0.01:1`, so I need to be able to get result for fractional values as well.

Comment: func(0.1) contains complex number and can be converted to numerical value.

Comment: how can there be a complex part? Each term in the infinite series is real valued.

Comment: Complex number can be created in many ways. When i take a look at result of func(0.1) , I see complex symbol in the output. I do not generate it. MATLAB generates the result.

Comment: No. the 'i' in the result is the one I gave as input and not iota. Its symbolically represented. Change `cosfun_hat(a,i)` to `cosfun_hat(a,k)` and you'll see the symbol 'k' in the result obtained

Comment: I know i is not complex symbol. I have more than 10 years experience in MATLAB. Result contanis 1i which is complex symbol in MATLAB.